# Parsing a string in postgresql

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, parsing

Let's say I have column of datatype varchar, the column contains values similar to these

```
'My unique id [john3 UID=123]'
'My unique id [henry2 UID=1234]'
'My unique id [tom2 UID=56]'
'My unique id [jerry25 UID=98765]'
```

How can I get only the numbers after `UID=` in the strings using postgresql.
for eg in string `'My unique id [john3 UID=123]'` I want only `123`, similarly in string `'My unique id [jerry25 UID=98765]'` I want only `98765`
Is there a way in PostgreSQL to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```sql
SELECT col, REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '.*\[\w+ UID=(\d+)\].*$', '\1') AS uid
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

In case a given value might not match the above pattern, in which case you would want to return the entire original value, we can use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT col,
       CASE WHEN col LIKE '%[%UID=%]%'
            THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '.*\[\w+ UID=(\d+)\].*$', '\1')
            ELSE col END AS uid
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: You won't get a better answer than this one ;) +1 However, if you want a "non-regex" solution check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4d2fbea707482a6b0df811b0e1e03e83)

Comment: Thanks Tim, this works for me! Probably I need to go through regex in postgresql

Comment: Is there a way to return the value 0 if the REGEXP_REPLACE returns you only string, for example in case of `my name is jerry` the REGEXP_REPLACE will return `my name is jerry` instead of that can i return a value 0?

Comment: @kannappan I have given you a version which will behave as you expect.

Comment: @kannappan you can achieve by checking if the result is a number (if applicable) within a `case`. check [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=20243b1bb9b3d4da80a9bc0de48d89a3)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `regexp_matches` for a shorter regular expression:

```
select regexp_matches(col, '(?<=UID\=)\d+') from t;
```